# lineedit-password-character proprety not working in PyQT5

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5

I created a `QlineEdit`, the content of which I would like to mask, I resorted to the `QLineEdit.Password` `EchoMode`, but unfortunately it doesn't let me specify the mask character. I stumbled upon the `lineedit-password-character` `StyleSheet` proprety, but it does nothing.

```py
password_field.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
password_field.setStyleSheet("color: #88c0d0; border: 0; lineedit-password-character: 2731; selection-background-color: #88c0d0; selection-color: #2e3440;")
```

The mask character I want is `*`

```py
# Password field
password_field = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(window)
password_field.resize(input_window.width() - password_label.width() - input_field_offset - input_window_padding * 2, password_label.height())
password_field.move(password_label.x() + password_label.width() + input_field_offset, password_label.y())
password_field.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
password_field.setStyleSheet("color: #88c0d0; border: 0; lineedit-password-character: 61; selection-background-color: #88c0d0; selection-color: #2e3440;")
```

Comment: What happens if you change the requested character to something like 61 (i.e. the '=' character)?  Does that work?  It may just be that your fonts are incomplete.

Comment: Still the same. I'll edit the original post to show you how the code is looking

Comment: this doesn't seem like it would be very difficult to implement yourself.  Why not just give it a try?

Comment: Any advice on where to start, any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is defined by [QStyle::SH_LineEdit_PasswordCharacter](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp.html#2287), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663207/masking-qlineedit-text

Comment: The correct value to use for `*` (U+2731 HEAVY ASTERISK) is `10033`: i.e. you must use a *decimal integer*, since the stylesheet syntax doesn't understand hex values.

Comment: @AssaadElOualji I cannot reproduce this. When using the correct values, the password characters are always displayed as expected. What platform are you testing on? I am using Qt-5.15.7 on Linux with a DejaVu Sans font. Note that the password character is a only a *hint*, so there's no guarantee that the platform style will actually use it.

Comment: Setting the value to 10033 did not work. I am testing on Windows 10, and am using PyQt5-5.15.4 with the Roboto Mono font.

Comment: @AssaadElOualji Try setting a proxy-style [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4665230/984421) (but note that the reimplemented `styleHint` should return an integer rather than a string). If that doesn't change anything, it would imply that the style-hint is completely ignored on your system (or maybe Windows generally - I can't test that myself).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the ASCII value for '*' which is 42.
This worked for me.

```
password_field.setStyleSheet("color: #88c0d0; border: 0; lineedit-password-character: 42; selection-background-color: #88c0d0; selection-color: #2e3440;")
```

Comment: I am afraid changing the ASCII value changed nothing I am still prompted with the default password character